# Basic iteration over a table in java

Tags: java, for-loop

Using `com.google.common.collect.Table`. I have a function which returns to me a table of the sort `Table<ObjType,ObjType, Set<String>>`. I want to iterate over all the entries, and for each entry, to print a short message, of the sort:

> "For ObjType x and ObjType y, the value is [[here goes the actual string value]]"

.

I'm not really sure what is the correct syntax to loop on a table. The function itself that fills the table is a preexisting function, so I am not really familiar with the properties of `com.google.common.collect.Table`.

I tried looking online, but couldn't find basic explanation, only complicated examples, which are far ahead of the basic iteration I want to do.

`ObjType` is a type of class I am using, but I don't think it matters so much.

I want to do something of the sort of foreach but not sure on the syntax...

Comment: Just iterate over the [`Table.cellSet()`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#cellSet())

Comment: What would be the syntax then? Its still a bit unclear for me. Because cellSet() will return a triplet <ObjType,ObjType,Set<String>>, so it won't be comfortable to use "foreach".

Comment: It returns a `Set` with objects of type [`Table.Cell`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.Cell.html). These objects have methods to get row, column and value.

Comment: Robby got it right (and should post it all as an answer). Something like this: `for (Cell<ObjType, ObjType, Set<String>> cell : table.cellSet()) { logger.info("For {} and {}, the value is {}", cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn(), cell.getValue()); }`